# Fix Regular Expression to allow optional fields

Tags: java, regex

A data-line looks like this:

```
$POSL,VEL,SPL,,,4.1,0.0,4.0*12
```

The 7th field (4.1) is extracted to the named field `SPEED` using this Java Regexp.

```
\\$POSL,VEL,SPL,,,(?<SPEED>\\d+.\\d+),.*
```

New data has slightly changed.  The fields in 4,5,6 may now contain data:

```
$POSL,VEL,SPL,a,b,c,4.0,a,b,c,d
```

But, the Regexp is now returning zero.  Note: fields 4, 5, 6 may contain letters or numbers. But, they will not contain quoted Strings (so we don't need to worry about quoted commas).

Can someone offer a fix please?

Comment: To be the 7th field, you miss a comma in the first example and in the regex

Comment: Have you considered using a CSV parser, for example [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) rather than regular expressions?

Comment: Actually, I'm going to delete the question.  The underlying issue isn't about RegEx, it's a mistake in the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could optionally repeat chars a-zA-Z and digits using `,[A-Za-z0-9]*`

As there is 1 comma more in the second string, you can make that part optional.

If you are not interested in the last part, but only in the capturing group, you can omit `.*` at the end. If the value can also occur at the end of the string, you can end the pattern with an alternation `(?:,|$)`

Note to escape the dot in this part `\\d+\\.\\d+`

```
\$POSL,VEL,SPL,[A-Za-z0-9]*,[A-Za-z0-9]*,(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*,)?(?<SPEED>\d+\.\d+)(?:,|$)
```

In Java with double escaped backslashes

```
String regex = "\\$POSL,VEL,SPL,[A-Za-z0-9]*,[A-Za-z0-9]*,(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*,)?(?<SPEED>\\d+\\.\\d+)(?:,|$)";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7BX3aX/1)

Comment: Thanks for that.  The new fields may contain a decimal, such as 1.1.  So, I modified your selector to allow for a `.` character.

Comment: @ianmayo You can extend the character class by adding a dot, which could then also match a dot only. If you want to match either chars a-z or a digit with an optional decimal part, you could also use `(?:[A-Za-z]+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9.]*`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `\w+` for any digit/letter, for the fields 4, 5, 6

```
\\$POSL,VEL,SPL,\\w*,\\w*,\\w*,(?<SPEED>\\d+.\\d+),.*
```

### [`REGEX DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/eidsBY/1)

---

Note that in your post, the example and the regex may miss a comma to get the numbre as seventh field

---

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in first input one , was missing.

```
    package arraysAndStrings;
    
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    
    public class RegexGroupCapture {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String inputArr[] = { "$POSL,VEL,SPL,,,,4.1,0.0,4.0*12",
                    "$POSL,VEL,SPL,a,b,c,4.0,a,b,c,d" };
            for (String input : inputArr) {
                System.out.println(extractSpeed(input));
            }
        }
    
        private static float extractSpeed(String input) {
            float speed = 0;
            try {
                String regex = "\\$POSL,VEL,SPL,.*?,.*?,.*?,(?<SPEED>\\d+.\\d+),.*";
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    speed = Float.parseFloat(matcher.group(1));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return speed;
        }
    }

Output
=====
4.1
4.0
```

Comment: Close: there was actually an extra `,` mistakenly present in the second one.  Thanks for the thorough answer.